# Displaying Images output using Oracle Application

Tags: sql, report, oraclereports

I have a customized report and I created a paper layout with image on it (Reports Builder), then I deployed my report to Oracle Application. After I ran my report in html format using Oracle app, the image was not displayed.

How can I display the image and what are the clear steps to make?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Report Builder `v11.1.2.2.0`. By following next steps, i could manage to show the picture(`.jpeg`) file inside Reports' generated `.htm` file :

- Double-clicked on `Paper Layout` node and activated it :

  [image]
- Clicked on `Insert` from horizontal menu and then selected `Image` :

  [image]
- Clicking on `Browse`, added my logo to my report(`Aç` means `Open` here) :

  [image]
- Used `Generate To File` option and then selected `Paginated HTML CSS` :

  [image]
- Save As pop-up window opened, saved as an .htm file in my file
  system, and called by browser :

  [image]